# Using JQuery to find a PHP file from within the same Wordpress plugin directory so it can be loaded programatically

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, plugins, bind

I'm developing a Wordpress video plugin. I want the video to start loading AFTER the rest of the page has loaded. I have:

- Created videosplash.php which contains code to create a div #video-splash.
- Created videosplash-video.php which contains code for loading the video itself. This code works perfectly when it is included directly within the above DIV.
- Attempted to use jquery bind the second PHP file to div #video-splash with directions for this to happen AFTER the rest of the page has loaded.

**Both PHP files are within the same plugin directory.**

I've tried the following ways of doing this with no luck; and I can't find any clarification of the matter by searching online.

**Attempted Method 1**

As a JS script normally calls things from whatever directory it is running from, I would have thought this should work - but it doesn't:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind("load", function() {  
    $('#video-splash').load('videosplash-video.php');
}); 
</script>
```

**Attempted Method 2**

I've also tried this way to load the file dynamically, but I don't think the plugins_url is a valid means of calling the file in javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind("load", function() {  
    $('#video-splash').load( plugins_url('/assets/php/videosplash-video.php',__FILE__ ) );
}); 
</script>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).bind("load", function() {  
    $('#video-splash').load( plugins_url('/videosplash-video.php',__FILE__ ) );
}); 
</script>
```

What am I missing folks? And thank you in advance

Comment: PHP is a server side language.  It does not run in your browser.  It runs on the server, builds the result, and then the result is sent to the client.  jQuery is javascript.  It runs on your client.

Comment: Also as a side note, `bind()` has been a wrapper only for `on()` for a few versions of jQuery, and as of 3X is has been deprecated.  You should switch to use `on()` instead when making bindings.

Comment: Thanks for your replies! Appreciate your time. Charan has given me a genius solution :)

Comment: Does anyone want to fess up to the down-vote so they can explain why it was given, it'd be good to know for future reference? I'm hoping there's a good reason as I went to great lengths to meet all the criteria to ask a valid question. It can sometimes seem like people on this site can seek to be quite punitive in their treatment of those with lesser knowledge, which is a shame and not really in the spirit of the site imo.

Comment: Take that as a "No", then. Totally unnecessary down vote.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot include wordpress plugins url via javascript,

one thing you can do, first hide the video div by giving the style="display:none", then on load you can make it display:block using javascript

for example consider this following is your video div,

```
<div id="video-splash" style="display:none;">
 some video content inside
</div>
```

then use javascript to enable it after page load like this,

```
$(document).on("load", function() {  
    $('#video-splash').show();
});
```

Comment: Ahh! That's a really good idea mate, thank you! I can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you very, very much - appreciated!